# OrangeHrm Add Field in PIM Personal Details

Tags: symfony, orangehrm

I am new to OrangeHRM 3.3.2 I need to add new field in the Personal Details. I need your help. Thanx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might get better help if you provide the code you've already written, and an explanation of why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add fields to your OrangeHRM application by doing one of these.

1) Edit the database to contain your new field. Then edit the application **form template** using a new `ohrm_widget` (`ohrm widget` means an input field in the OrangeHRM system (ex. Test Field, Calendar, Dropdown, etc.)) and edit the controller function to pass your data to the backend. Then complete the DAO layer function to save your data at the database.

Ex:
If you are going to add a *preferred name* field for employees, then,

- Add the *preferred name* column to the data table
- Add the new *preferred name* input field to the form template
- Add the new parameter in the controller layer to pass it to the backend
- Complete the DAO layer function to save the *preferred name* parameter in the data table

2) In OrangeHRM 5.x you have the support from the application itself to create the custom fields for your entities. (I don't know about the 3.x versions.)